# Running maven command remotely using ssh

Tags: maven, ssh

Trying to execute a script on the remote aws centos machine using the command mentioned below

```
ssh root@hostname script
```

Everything works fine until the script comes to a maven command. For example "mvn package" in the script. Getting the error below.
    bash: mvn: command not found

Comment: `root@hostname` does not have `mvn` in it's path. Are you sure it's installed on the remote host? Did you try with the full path to `mvn`?

Comment: I have added it to the path. I do run the same script on remote machine all the time. So, I'm sure about that.

Comment: @nakeer Do you run it as `root` when logged in on remote machines as well? If not, what's PATH for the user you use? Did you check what's displayed when you insert an `echo "${PATH}"` in your `script`?

Comment: you are right @GeroldBroser. I have created another script with      echo "${PATH}". Its gives different results when running the same script from local machine and logging in remote machine as root and running the same script.